# Problem setting div height in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, height

I have a div with a pretty curve background image so it does rounded corners on all browsers.

The problem is that in Internet explorer, the background image is followed by a background-coloured line. If I set the div's height, Firefox and Chrome will both shrink the height of the div, however IE will not adjust anything.

Here's my CSS. Note that the rest of the CSS is applied in IE (and FF/Chrome) fine.

```
#MSBottomSlot .topCurve {
    background:url("images/topCurve.jpg"); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:10px; /* Changing this value does nothing in IE */
    width:100%;
}
```

**Is there some IE 'gotcha' regarding height that I'm missing?**

Here are some additional details:

- The line does not appear in FF or Chrome.
- There's little javascript on the page, nothing that would impact how this renders.
- Other changes to the css get applied to the div.

Comment: Maybe adding overflow: hidden to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if i could understand right, the height is not effected becasue of the line-height and font-size. so you must add

```
line-height: 0;
font-size: 0;
```

Comment: This is possible. Although I have no content, it might still be displaying the space where content might go.

Comment: this was the problem. Thanks so much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Remember to set the doctype so the browser doesn't go into quirksmode

First line of your html document should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You could also use a more traditional xhtml doctype like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

But i will recommend the first type which is html5 compliant and works fine in IE as well even tho they don't do html5, and it looks so much better than that awful xhtml doctype ;)

Also remember that you cannot apply height to `inline` elements, only block level elements, so your element needs to be `display: block` or `display: inline-block` or similar ;)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I'll look into it and see if this helps. (Sorry I can't +1 yet, not enough rep)

Comment: Doctype was already set, so this wasn't the problem. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying overflow:hidden to your CSS

```
#MSBottomSlot .topCurve {
    background:url("images/topCurve.jpg"); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:10px; /* Changing this value does nothing in IE */
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Comment: A good suggestion, I'll take a look and let you know how it turned out.

Comment: the overflow wasn't the problem (line height was). Thanks for your help!